# Do I need to install keras 2.0 seprately after installing tensorflow 1.3?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I just upgraded my tf from 1.0 to tf 1.3 (pip install --upgrade tensorflow) . I know keras 2.0 became part of tensorflow since tf version 1.2. However, when I import keras and check its version it still shows 1.2. Am I supposed to upgrade keras also? if so, then what does "[the Keras API will now become available directly as part of TensorFlow, starting with TensorFlow 1.2](https://blog.keras.io/introducing-keras-2.html)" mean?

Comment: If you want to use keras in that way, don't import keras but use directly the api integrated in tf : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras

Comment: I just installed Keras 2 and it works fine on a simple example. I still don't understand why I had to do that if Keras is now part of tensorflow (as tf v1.2)

Comment: when you used keras with tensorflow, did you import it that way : from "tf.contrib import keras" ?

If you want to use it through tensorflow, you have to use the library integrated in tensorflow... Which is located in tf.contrib.keras... Then you can use tf.contrib.keras.conv1D for example... which is a 1D convolutional layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you don't need to install keras 2.0 separately. (See: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras)

**Do** this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
```

**Don't** do this (Unless you really need framework independent code):

```py
import keras

model = keras.Sequential()
```